# Программа на Android не соединяется по HTTPS

Tags: android, https, httpsurlconnection

Программа отрабатывает по http, но https не хочет не в какую. Вылетает на шаге взятия потока из connect. Пытался разными методами, но все методы рубятся на потоке.

---

Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dilun.testik">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Код с двумя разными методами:

```
public class test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String urlStr = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/4";
    HttpsURLConnection https = null;
    private JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    private byte[] bytes = null;

   /* private test(JSONObject jsonObject, byte[] bytes) {
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
   */

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Log.d("LOG___", "Testing 1");
            sendGet();
           // ooooooo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    // https GET request
    private void sendGet() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            Log.d("LOG__", "url : " + url);
            https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            Log.d("LOG__", "HttpsURLConnection : OK" );
            https.setRequestMethod("GET");
            https.setDoOutput(true);
            https.setDoInput(true);
            https.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            Log.d("LOG__", "Metods : OK" );
            Log.d("LOG__", "https : " + https.toString());

            DataInputStream inputStream = (DataInputStream) https.getInputStream();
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            Log.d("LOG__", "inputStream : " + inputStream.toString());
           // inputStream.writeUTF(jsonObject.toString());
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            Log.d("LOG__", "jsonObject : " + jsonObject.toString());
          //  inputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            Log.d("LOG__", "bytes : " + bytes);
            //inputStream.flush();
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            Log.d("LOG__", "flush : " );

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("LOG__", "URL : URLException: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.d("LOG__", "URL : URLException: " +e.getStackTrace().toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("LOG__", "IOException : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Второй метод через OkHttpClient
    private void ooooooo(){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        Log.d("LOG__", "client : ok");
        String url = urlStr;

        Request.Builder request = new Request.Builder();
        request.url(url);
        request.get();
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        Log.d("LOG__", "request : ok");
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request.build()).execute();
            String responses = response.body().string();
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            Log.d("LOG__", "response : ok");
            System.out.println(response );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

    }
```

---

---

Логи: Чисто с моим выводом:

```
10-10 22:50:17.297 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG___: Testing 1
10-10 22:50:17.297 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG__: url : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/4
10-10 22:50:17.302 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG__: HttpsURLConnection : OK
10-10 22:50:17.302 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG__: Metods : OK
10-10 22:50:17.302 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG__: https : com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/4
```

---

с полным выводом (тестинг на Genymotion):

```
                                      [ 10-10 22:50:16.825  1037: 1065 D/         ]
                                      HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xef797e30, tid 1065
10-10 22:50:17.053 2438-2438/com.example.dilun.testik I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-10 22:50:17.182 2438-2438/com.example.dilun.testik W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-10 22:50:17.297 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG___: Testing 1
10-10 22:50:17.297 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG__: url : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/4
10-10 22:50:17.302 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG__: HttpsURLConnection : OK
10-10 22:50:17.302 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG__: Metods : OK
10-10 22:50:17.302 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik D/LOG__: https : com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/4
10-10 22:50:17.657 2438-2460/com.example.dilun.testik A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6f6f477 in tid 2460 (AsyncTask #1)
10-10 22:50:17.708 120-120/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-10 22:50:17.708 120-120/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:5.0/LRX21M/genymotion03202336:userdebug/test-keys'
10-10 22:50:17.708 120-120/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
10-10 22:50:17.708 120-120/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
10-10 22:50:17.708 120-120/? I/DEBUG: pid: 2438, tid: 2460, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.example.dilun.testik <<<
10-10 22:50:17.708 120-120/? I/DEBUG: signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xf6f6f478
10-10 22:50:17.713 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     eax e2e3c3bc  ebx e2e79008  ecx 0000000c  edx e2e3c3b8
10-10 22:50:17.713 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     esi e2e79004  edi f70533e4
10-10 22:50:17.713 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000077  xss 0000002b
10-10 22:50:17.714 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     eip f6f6f478  ebp 00000008  esp e30fe718  flags 00210202
10-10 22:50:17.714 120-120/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
10-10 22:50:17.714 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00096478  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_memcmp+136)
10-10 22:50:17.714 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0001db41  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_finished+145)
10-10 22:50:17.714 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000205dc  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+2220)
10-10 22:50:17.714 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000153e4  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
10-10 22:50:17.714 120-120/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00393918  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat
10-10 22:50:17.812 120-120/? I/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
10-10 22:50:17.812 1037-1061/system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
10-10 22:50:17.812 1037-1665/system_process E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
10-10 22:50:17.819 1037-2471/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.dilun.testik/.MainActivity
10-10 22:50:17.832 770-770/? I/Zygote: Process 2438 exited due to signal (4)
10-10 22:50:18.122 1037-2471/system_process I/WindowManager: Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{2570c18b ActivityRecord{1b119b5a u0 com.example.dilun.testik/.MainActivity t37 f}} appWin=Window{230599bd u0 Starting com.example.dilun.testik} drawState=4
10-10 22:50:18.123 1037-2471/system_process E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
10-10 22:50:18.124 1037-2471/system_process W/ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
                                                               android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                                                                   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:701)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:852)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2754)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2611)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2453)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11511)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11408)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12087)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11603)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
10-10 22:50:18.126 267-267/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/2438/oom_score_adj; errno=2
10-10 22:50:18.133 1037-1056/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo) from ActivityManagerService.java:12038 waiters=1 for 301ms
10-10 22:50:18.133 1037-1056/system_process W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10059/pid_2438/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
10-10 22:50:18.133 1037-1056/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.example.dilun.testik (pid 2438) has died
10-10 22:50:18.152 1037-2477/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
10-10 22:50:18.153 1037-1060/system_process D/Atlas: Validating map...
10-10 22:50:18.191 1037-2477/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                              [ 10-10 22:50:18.192  1037: 2477 D/         ]
                                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe400b100, tid 2477
10-10 22:50:18.235 1335-1570/com.android.launcher3 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-10 22:50:18.235 1335-1570/com.android.launcher3 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xef671860, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-10 22:50:18.325 1037-2477/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-10 22:50:18.351 1037-2477/system_process W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-10 22:50:18.351 1037-2477/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe4053b20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-10 22:50:18.835 1335-1570/com.android.launcher3 W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
10-10 22:50:25.629 1037-1367/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 1357:com.android.printspooler/u0a50 (adj 15): empty #17
10-10 22:50:25.630 1037-1367/system_process W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10050/pid_1357/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
10-10 22:50:25.639 1037-1332/system_process W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10050/pid_1357/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
10-10 22:55:11.680 117-117/? D/Genyd: Received Set Clipboard
10-10 22:55:11.680 117-117/? D/Genymotion: Received Set Clipboard
10-10 22:55:18.166 1037-1055/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4926574 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@318bbcb0
10-10 22:58:03.439 117-117/? D/Genyd: Received Set Clipboard
10-10 22:58:03.439 117-117/? D/Genymotion: Received Set Clipboard
10-10 22:59:33.458 117-117/? D/Genyd: Received Set Clipboard
10-10 22:59:33.458 117-117/? D/Genymotion: Received Set Clipboard
10-10 22:59:57.304 117-117/? D/Genyd: Received Set Clipboard
10-10 22:59:57.307 117-117/? D/Genymotion: Received Set Clipboard
```

Comment: Ваш метод с `OkHttpClient` у меня отработал корректно.

Comment: Еще раз попробовал, такая же ерунда. ERROR:  10-11 02:15:52.172 2582-2607/com.example.dilun.testik A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf6f0d477 in tid 2607 (AsyncTask #1)
   Куда копать даже и не знаю

Comment: @Dilun7495 проблема не связана с соединением, обратите внимание на эту строку: `Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml`

Comment: Спасибо, понял буду доступ разрешать на запись файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в эмуляторе genymotion. На реальном устройстве пошло.